# IHttpActionResult method cannot return NotFound()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a web API for my website and have ran into a problem.

At the moment, the API is supposed to return details from the specified user.

This is my controller for accounts:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Net;
using RoditRepoAPIV2.Models;

namespace RoditRepoAPIV2.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        Account[] products = new Account[] 
        { 
            //accounts will be added...
        };

        public IEnumerable<Account> GetAllAccounts()
        {
            return products;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult GetAccount(int id)
        {
            var account = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
            if (account == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(account);
        }

    }
}
```

Although most of this code is copied from the tutorial [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api), Visual Studio complains that '`NotFound()`' and '`Ok(account)`' do not exist in the current context. I have updated **all** of the NuGet packages to version 5.1.2+ and I still get this error.

I have done some research and found that it seems to work for other people...

I would much appreciate it if anyone could respond with a working solution!
Thank you.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to inherit your controller from `ApiConroller` - that is where these methods are defined:

```
public class AccountController : ApiController
```

Answer (score 2):

from aspnet core 6

Replace

```
return NotFound() and HttpNotFound();
```

with

```
return new StatusCodeResult(404);
```